# Grasp hand pose estimation with Machine learning

Tags: computer-vision

What I'm trying to do is..

Dataset: Pictures of a hand holding a stick, and I know the 3d position of joints, or 3D pose of each picture. Pictures are taken from same position, so hand is the only one that moves. 
Input: A picture of hand
Output: 3D Hand Pose Is this possible, and if so, how could this be done? Since I'm a newbie to ML, I want to get ideas for good understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but it will be a hard research project.

Because the problem requires such complex output, a machine learning approach to the problem will take a huge number of training examples, more than you could generate by hand. A good approach might be to make a small program that can 3D-render an image of a hand in pose x, with random lighting, random hand size, etc. Then feed millions of those training images to a convolutional neural net with deep learning, where the final output neurons encode the poses.

Using that same program, an alternative approach would be to do gradient descent on the pose, repeatedly rendering poses until you get the best match. That's called a generative model. It doesn't involve a neural net, but it would probably be slow. There are no doubt other approaches too.

If you're interested, Microsoft has been working on this problem to enable new types of Xbox Kinect games: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/fully-articulated-hand-tracking/

All in all though, if you're new to computer vision and machine learning, I'd recommend starting with simpler challenges first.

Comment: I have a software which converts 3d joints to the suitable pose, so in fact 3d position of joints is the required. Sorry that I forgot to mention about that. Pictures are not RGB-D for now, will this be a big problem?

Comment: With the deep neural net approach, the "label" for each training example will be a 1-D array containing 3d positions of joints. The "feature vector" is the RGB image of the rendered hand. The absence of depth data will certainly reduce your final accuracy, but it's probably possible to get some results without depth information.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. how long do you think would take to implement this kind of problem? i'm not capable to create a new network, thus i'll appreciate if there's a similar project..

Comment: For someone knowledgeable in neural nets, it will probably take a few hundred hours of work to get initial results. Since you're new to ML you should first do things to become knowledgeable. I recommend the free Coursera Machine Learning course by Andrew Ng: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning